# Convert unicode text field in sqlite db to its native ascii representation

Tags: c++, objective-c, unicode, type-conversion, ascii

I've got sqlite bad formatted table which contain some strings in unicode format and they're displayed as such in prompt command line.

```
sqlite> select * from myTable;
1|条湥却慴畴s|2
```

But in fact, it represent a regular "English" string in ascii.

However, this data is in fact regular ascii based string. so in order to make the conversion I use python to see the unicode building blocks

```
>>> str="条湥却慴畴s"
>>> str
'\xe6\x9d\xa1\xe6\xb9\xa5\xe5\x8d\xb4\xe6\x85\xb4\xe7\x95\xb4s'
```

In the second phase I convert it to the ascii format. However, it still represented the long format.

```
>>> str2 = unicode(str,"utf8")
>>> str2
u'\u6761\u6e65\u5374\u6174\u7574s'
```

But if I take pair-by-pair and convert it to its ascii representation, I get the original string expected to be found there (except for the trailing 's' which I'm not sure what does it represent...)

```
67 61 6e 65 53 74 61 74 75 73 ==> 'ganeStatus'
```

Is there any way to perform all these iteration programmatically in c++ or objective-c ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the data should have been stored in UTF-8 format, but your input appears to be UTF16-LE format, probably created by a Windows program. You have to convert to UTF8

In ASCII or UTF8, `'a'` is represented as a single byte `0x65`
In UTF16-LE, `'a'` is 2 bytes `0x65 0x00`

The `s` at the end is probably due to undefined behavior because the string is not null terminated.

Note that a regular c-string has one zero at the end. But UTF16 needs 2 zeros at the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <cassert>
#include <locale>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[] = "\x67\0\x61\0\x6e\0\x65\0\x53\0\x74\0\x61\0\x74\0\x75\0\x73\0\0\0";
    std::string trans = 
        std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, 
        char16_t>{}.to_bytes((char16_t*)buf);
    std::cout << trans << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

(if this was on Windows platform you would use `wchar_t` instead of `char16_t`

[See online example](https://ideone.com/VDSVqh)